# Passing double/float through URL to Web Api query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I got a Web Api project, and I want to call a api controller through this URL:

```
Http://localhost:3030/GetByCoordinates/[[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,0]]
```

It works fine, but when I try to add a double number (like 1.1 instead of 1) the browser throws 404 not found exception, because the dot make it look like another address.

How can i handle doubles ?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding '/' at the end of the URL, e.g.

```
Http://localhost:3030/GetByCoordinates/[[0,1],[1,1.1],[1,0],[0,0]]/
```

Reference: [Why is my Web API method with double args not getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387974/why-is-my-web-api-method-with-double-args-not-getting-called)

Comment: I tested this with WebApi2 and it works. If you don't add the slash at the end, you can't have a float at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly the query string, but unless you can configure your MVC project (or, more specifcally, probably IIS) to allow/manage certain mappings (or *not* to manage them, in a given case perhaps) then you should be able to translate the character from one form to another.

That is, you could swap periods out for `%2E`, and swap them back in on the server side.

Comment: How can i configure my mvc project routing or mapping to do so ?