# MVC WebAPI2 attribute routing using a path ending with a route parameter of type double

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

We are having an issue with WebApi2 attribute routing.  We recently upgraded to MVC5 and Web Api 2.  As part of the upgrade we shifted our Web Api to use Attribute routing.

One of our API calls allows for data to be requested using a latitude and longitude bounding box.

https://myapi.com/v1/things/area/{toplat}/{leftlon}/{botlat}/{rightlon}

This worked in the previous api, but not in the new one.  We can't find a configuration that allows this to work.  The final argument {rightlon} is a double and the xx.XXX is interpreted as a file extension.

Specifying the parameters as a double {toplat:double} had no impact. We can't easily force the legacy clients to update to include a trailing slash as some posts suggest.  This config change also didn't work for us.
[Why is my Web API method with double args not getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387974/why-is-my-web-api-method-with-double-args-not-getting-called)

Has anyone found a way to use attribute routing in WebApi2 to allow for a route that has a double/decimal/float as the last route parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The linked article did include the solution but also needed the correct format on the Attribute Routing.

[HttpGet]        [Route("~/v1/things/area/{toplat:double}/{leftlon:double}/{botlat:double}/{rightlon:double}")]

in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```