# Floating-point numbers in restangular

Tags: floating-point, restangular

I am using restangular to handle Rest API. Here is my call in javascript:

```
callApi: function(doubleOne, doubleTwo, doubleThree, doubleFour) {
        return Restangular.all('api/test/' + doubleOne+ '/' + doubleTwo+ '/' + doubleThree+ '/' + doubleFour).getList();
},
```

And this is the beginning of the api in the backend in c#:

```
[Route("api/test/{doubleOne}/{doubleTwo}/{doubleThree}/{doubleFour}")]
public IList<ViewModel> GetTest(double doubleOne, double doubleTwo, double doubleThree, double doubleFour)
   {
      ...
   }
```

If the doubles contain something like **56.9883432** or **56,9883432** I do not get in the backend code. If the doubles are "normal" numbers like **56** I get in the backend code.

Now I ask me if there is a limitation of using restangular. Is it really not possible to use restangular with floating-point numbers? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The fault is not on restangular, it is because of web api. 
Please look at: [Why is my Web API method with double args not getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387974/why-is-my-web-api-method-with-double-args-not-getting-called)