# WebAPI : Min/max double for RouteAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following API method:

```
[Route("GetEditorialRequestsByCoordinates/{lat:double}/{lng:double}")]
[AutomapperExceptionApiFilterAttribute]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEditorialRequestsByCoordinates(double lat, double lng)
{

}
```

it works fine for request like:

```
GET /v1/api/request/GetEditorialRequestsByCoordinates/48.999/2.777/
```

But I want to add limit (minimum and maximum) for lat and lng.

Follow this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

> max   Matches an integer with a maximum value.    {x:max(10)}
>
> min   Matches an integer with a minimum value.    {x:min(10)}

Try to create such route:

```
[Route("GetEditorialRequestsByCoordinates/{lat:double:min(-90):max(90)}/{lng:double:min(-180):max(180)}")]
```

and I get 404 error. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you give tells that functions works for **integer**

**max:  *Matches an integer with a maximum value.*  {x:max(10)}**

I think it does not work for double.

you can see this [link](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/10/route-matching-overriding-404-asp-net-web-api/) to create your own IHttpRouteConstraint.

Comment: I saw it, but understood it as we can set max(min) value only as integer value, but range will work for any number type

Comment: @OlegSh, you got this to work with range and double?

Comment: if you tell me I will write a code for you which support double for you.