# float in REST-API call

Tags: rest

how can one send float values to a RESTful API?

```
/api/set/integername/49

/api/set/charname/B

/api/set/floatname/49.33
```

The third one doesn't work.

```
404: Not Found
```

Can float values be encoded somehow to make this possible or do I have to wrap it in a json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do something simple like convert the decimal point to an underscore :)  It's less messy than URL encoding.

Do you have to support scientific notation (ex 1.5e+20)?  In that case you'll have to deal with + and -.
(though - doesn't need encoding)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question to [Passing double/float through URL to Web Api query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528819/passing-double-float-through-url-to-web-api-query-string)

The answer provided there was to add a slash to the end of the querystring. I've just tested that with a blank Microsoft WebApi2 project and it works a treat.